# Set Kendo Grid POPUP editor values using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using Kendo Grid with POPUP editing.

On edit POPup I'm having a textbox like below.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { style = "width:175px" })
```

Then I set this textbox value using Jquery

```
 $("#FirstName").val("my name");
```

When I submit the popup to save the values it does not pass these values to controller. However, if I type a value on the textbox, then it works fine.

Why is it not working with the values set through Jquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Value set directly on editor pop-up / templates from jquery for some old reasons is not updating the model. I also faced the same issue, below is my solution.

```
var uid = $(".k-edit-form-container").closest("[data-role=window]").data("uid"),

model = $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.getByUid(uid);

model.set("FirstName", "my name");
```

Do let me know if this is not what you were looking for!

Answer (score 6):

There is a simpler solution:

```
$("#FirstName").val("my name").trigger("change");
```

Comment: Although I didn't try the accepted answer, this worked perfectly. I prefer simplicity. I would really like to know why the Telerik Grid Popup works this way though.

Comment: I guess it's because the grid popup uses [Kendo UI MVVM bindings](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/bindings/value). The docs state: "Value binding supports only DOM elements with a value property and widgets that have a value() method. The DOM element or widget also must fire a change event when the user changes its value."